# RestHighLevelClient v/s ElasticsearchClient Java client in Elasticsearch 8.x to search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have used RestHighLevelClient to search and retrieve data as List<Map<String, Object>>.

```
final SearchResponse response = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    RestStatus statusCode = response.status();
    log.info("Status code : {} ", statusCode.getStatus());
    if(RestStatus.OK.equals(response.status())) {
        final SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
        Long totalHits = hits.getTotalHits();
        log.info("Total number of hits : {} ", totalHits);
        final SearchHit[] results = hits.getHits();
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>(totalHits.intValue());
        for(SearchHit hit : results) {
            final Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
            list.add(sourceAsMap);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

The signature of search() in ElasticSearchClient is different. It requires to provide Class as a part of the method parameter. In  my case, I do not want to cast it into any concrete object. I tried to use "Object.class" (e.g. elasticSearchClient.search(searchRequest, Object.class). But It did not provide me the list of Map which I used to get in RestHighLevelClient. My question is how do I extract the List<Map <String, Object>> from the response using the new API?

```
 SearchResponse<Object> response = elasticSearchClient.search(searchRequest, Object.class);
        List<Hit<Object>> hits = response.hits().hits();
        for (Hit<Object> hit : hits) {
            // how do I get Map<String, Object> here? 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `ObjectNode` class:

```
ObjectNode json = response.source();
String name = json.get("name").asText();
logger.info("Product name " + name);
```

Source: [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/reading.html#_reading_raw_json)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to cast it to Map.class to get the expected result.

```
 SearchResponse<Map> response = elasticSearchClient.search(searchRequest, Map.class);
    List<Hit<Map>> hits = response.hits().hits();
    for (Hit<Object> hit : hits) {
           Map<String, Object> source = hit.source();
    }
```